# How to add a filter in view with list of values

Tags: views

I have a content type which has a Number(Integer) field.

I created a view. I would like to expose the price field as a filter to the public like the following with a list of price range.

[image]

In view > filter criteria, I added the price field. How to add the list of values with price range?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a list of ranges you can use the **Grouped filters** option with Widget Type: Select, instead of Single filter.

[image]

Then you can add your groups below. Each group becomes an option in your select list.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I like to hide the label from the filters. How to set "Price Range" as the placeholder for the price field?

Comment: I believe you would have to use a form alter for that. Here's a reference: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/theme-development/2012-06-28/add-html-5-placeholder-in-views-exposed-filter